# Could not override magento admin controller in Magento 1.9

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to override admin Newsletter template controller. I have done the following thing. But it's not getting override.

Modules config.xml

```
<frontend>
        <routers>
            <company>
                <args>
                    <module>Company_Newsletter</module>
                    <frontName>newsletterarchive</frontName>
                </args>
            </company>
        </routers>
    </frontend>

    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Company_Newsletter before="Mage_Adminhtml_Newsletter_TemplateController">Company_Newsletter_Adminhtml_TemplateController</Company_Newsletter>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
```

My controller placed in

> app\code\local\Company\Newsletter\controllers\Adminhtml\TemplateController.php

and this is my controller code.

```
include_once("Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Newsletter/TemplateController.php");
class Company_Newsletter_Adminhtml_TemplateController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Newsletter_TemplateController {
    public function editAction()
    {
        die;
    }
}
```

It's not getting override. Is there any problem with this code?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Company_Newsletter before="Mage_Adminhtml">Company_Newsletter_Adminhtml</Company_Newsletter>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
```

Now check
And  **your TemplateController.php location should be Company>Newsletter>controllers>Adminhtml>Newsletter>**

```
<?php
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('Mage_Adminhtml').DS.'Newsletter'.DS.'TemplateController.php'
class Company_Newsletter_Adminhtml_Newsletter_TemplateController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Newsletter_TemplateController {
    public function editAction()
    {
        die;
    }
}
```

Comment: i have tried as you said but no luck! Even it's not executing my controller file.

Comment: are you want to add new controller..??

Comment: I need to override an action in Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Newsletter/TemplateController.php

Comment: any other suggestion?

Comment: I have achieved my requirement with this blog post [link](http://www.bubblecode.net/en/2012/01/17/magento-how-to-override-a-controller-easily/) . Don't know what's the exact problem with above code.